# Blog in multiple languages on WordPress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, multi-language

Does wordpress.com support multiple languages at the same time?  I know it does support changing the main language, but I can't find anything about how one would go about setting up multiple languages at the same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, wordpress.com does not support multilanguage blogs. The solution would be to make one blog per language and link them via the sidebar.

Reference: [Multi-language blog on wordpress.com](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/multi-language-blog-on-wordpresscom)